# CSS inline padding behavior

Tags: css

For some reason padding on an anchor tag overflows out of the parent <li></li>. When adding display:block it no longer overflows. The same happens with margins instead of padding. Why is the padding ignored when sizing <li></li>?

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{list-style:none;text-align:right;}
ul a{padding:3px;}
```

Comment: what do you mean by sizing <li></li> ?

Comment: @synxmax I mean that it overflows, the size of the list item is just big enough for its height, not height+padding

Comment: `ul{list-style:none;text-align:right; line-height:1;}
ul a {padding:0px; }`

Comment: line height does nothing except make the line shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be an issue with `padding-left` or `padding-right`. But vertical padding won't work on inline element like `<a />`.

Comment: @lnrbob Is it part of the CSS spec or just a browser problem, because I couldn't find any information, and there seems to be no reason not to allow inline vertical padding. Is there a CSS workaround?

Comment: this is an intentional part of the visual formatting model of CSS - it's one of the main aspects that separates block and inline elements. Essentially inline elements just show content 'in the line'. To get around this there is `display:block` or the half-way-house `display:inline-block` (not fully supported on older browsers). Floating elements will force block behaviour as well. Why can't you use `display:block` here? I almost always do with anchors in lists

Comment: @lnrbob I am trying to do a menu without floats, by setting list items to display inline you get a nice menu except for overflowing padding

Comment: unfortunately that's the price you pay. As mentioned before the idea of `display:inline` is that it fits in a line and doesn't break that line's layout. If you don't want to use float use inline block for the  `<a />` (or the `<li />` and `display:block` for the `<a />`). I realise it seem over complicated to use floating but this is pretty much the purpose for which it was made.

Comment: @lnrbob Just one last thing, how does <img /> fit in if its supposed to be the height of the line? I fail to see the logic according to this, images should be block too.

Comment: apologies if I have added to the confusion - that is the way I think of inline elements to get on day to day. It is not an all-encompassing rule and should not be treated as such. If you would like the full explanation it can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html

Comment: cool, glad that helped - just be aware that the older browsers (like ie6 and 7) need to have haslayout forced on a display:inline element to get the same rendering. Lots of articles online on how to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

The width of a parent element may be defined, causing your a to push outside of the element. Try using Web Inspector or Firebug to see if the `<ul>`, `<li>` or other containing `<div>`s have a defined width.

Comment: I already did, the code I posted is the bare minimum to get the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because li is an inline element.  Try this out:

**CSS**

```
ul { list-style:none;text-align:right; }
ul li { display:block; }
ul li a { display:block;  margin:30px; }
```

Comment: sorry, but I am specifically trying to avoid using display:block or float:right. Any idea why this is though? I see no point in overflowing inline padding.

Comment: @anonymous Any particular reason you want to avoid these methods?  I'm just trying to get a better idea how to help you on this.